# Is there a way to have two getters with different accesses and use in for loop one of them?

Tags: c++, for-loop, oop, getter

```cpp
class Foo {
    // friend Bar;

    public: const std::list<int*>& numbs () const { // (1)
        return mNumbs;
    }

    protected: std::list<int*>& numbs () { // (2)
        return mNumbs;
    }

    private: std::list<int*> mNumbs;
};

int main () {
    Foo foo;
    for (const auto& e : foo.numbs()) { // (3)
        // some work...
    }
}
```

My intention is to force to use (1) method for clients and (2) method for friends of Foo class.
However compiler is trying to use (2) method that is protected in for statement and error is occured (3):

```cpp
std::__cxx11::list<int*>& Foo::numbs()’ is protected within this context
```

I found some solutions:

1. Changing name of (2) method (to numbs_ for example).
2. Changing access class of (2) method to public (I'm not satisfied with that).

Does anyone know any better idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Method 1 is **not** a better match since `foo` is not a constant object. It will only be called if your object is constant.

If your callers choose to mark the object as a `const`, only then the error will go away. For instance, this will work as expected:

```
const Foo foo;
for (const auto& e : foo.numbs()) { // (3)
    // some work...
}
```

Seems like a bad idea to design it like this imo.

On a side note, you also need to know that visibility and accessibility in C++ are different things. Both methods are visible, but only one is accessible. And the one which is a better match is not accessible outside the type or derived types. Hence the error.

P.S.: As noted in the comments, a `const_cast<>` will also achieve the same effect.

Comment: `Foo foo; for (const auto& e : const_cast<const Foo &>(foo).numbs()) { ... }` should work, too, or simply: `Foo foo; const Foo &cfoo = foo; for (const auto& e : cfoo.numbs()) { ... }`, if the caller can't change `foo` itself to be `const` for some reason.

Comment: Yup, but either way why design an API like that where intuitive code doesn't work. Why force your callers to insert a cast or cv-qualifier just to iterate over some member.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So how to achive my intention: ro reference for clients and rw reference for Bar friend? Two methods with different names is best solution?

Comment: Ever heard of CRTP? Consider yourself blessed if you haven't. Kidding aside, I believe you can drop the `const` qualifier from the first method and get the expected behavior.

Comment: Also, I've discovered that removment of (2) method allow to compile the code.

Comment: That's because of the accessibility/visibility conflict I noted above.

Comment: @TanveerBadar, when I remove front const from (1) then I have discards qualifiers error.